# how to update archive and table view cell

Tags: uitableview, archive, master-detail

I'm working on a MasterDetail app, and having an issue updating my itemCells.  Using the code from the DetailViewController below, I had hoped to be able to access the detail view after touching the cell (for which there is a custom ItemCell), edit the contents in the text fields, hit the save button, update the item data, and pop back to the MasterViewController.

**From DetailViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender
```

{

```
RoomItem *item = [[RoomItem alloc] initWithName:[_roomTxt text] Building:[_buildingTxt text]];

//add item is an addObject method i've placed in RoomList.m
[[RoomList sharedStore] addItem:item];

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

It's probably obvious that this is only creating a new table view item and not updating the original, but I'm a silly noob and can't locate anything in the documentation to help me figure this out.

Ideas?
Please let me know if I'm not providing enough information/code to explain the situation accurately.

Also, is there a way to achieve the same functionality through a UITableViewAccessory?

Thanks.

This is what worked for me.  It seems I was not properly fetching the core data entity.  However, the objectAtIndex query is still an issue since it only updates the RoomItem at index:0.  **How can a get the index of the RoomItem I'm trying to update?**

**Edit:**

```
- (RoomItem *)updateItemWithRoom:(NSString *)room Building:(NSString *)building
{
NSError *error = nil;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RoomItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

RoomItem *currentRoomItem = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
request = nil;

[currentRoomItem setRoom:room];
[currentRoomItem setBuilding:building];

[self saveChanges];

return currentRoomItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call on viewdidappear to Reload the Data from the table view with reload data.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't know exactly how to go about doing that.  Do you mean that I need to import the MasterViewController.h into the DetailViewController.m, and call the viewDidAppear from the former?

Comment: You have to implement in the MasterViewController the `-(void)viewDidAppear:animated` Method. On the Method you can reload the complete TableData with `[self.myTableView reloadData]`

Comment: See update above for partially resolved code.  I'm still having an issue...and thanks for your help mariusLAN.

Comment: Ultimately, what I need is to fetch the objectIndex of the RoomItem being edited and pass it to updateRoomItem.  Is there a way of doing this in the DetailViewController?

Comment: you could hand the index to the detailviewcontroller